# How to insert the result in the desired row? SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need the result that I got to be inserted in the right row.

```
DECLARE @DiscPrice float;
SET @DiscPrice = (SELECT Prod.priceProd - Prod.priceProd / 100 * Prod.disc 
                  FROM Prod 
                  WHERE id_prod = 1);

UPDATE Prod 
SET priceDisc = @DiscPrice 
WHERE id_prod = 1;

SELECT * FROM Prod;
```

That is, instead of `WHERE id_prod = 1`, there was something that inserted the desired result in all rows.

I'm not sure I made myself clear, but I hope that you will understand.

Comment: Why don't you `UPDATE` your table directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want

```
UPDATE Prod 
SET priceDisc = ((priceProd - priceProd) / 100) * disc
WHERE id_prod = 1;
```

There is no need to use a variable or a query to assign the value to it.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I get it. But how can I make sure that the result is inserted in the desired row, so as not to write each time for a separate row `WHERE id_prod = n ;`

Comment: @Maxim The `WHERE` clause determine which row will be updated according to the condition specified. If you're looking to `UPDATE` all rows then remove the `WHERE` clause

Comment: But it so happens that the same result is inserted in all rows. But I need the percentage to be calculated separately for each row, and insert the result in the desired row.

Comment: @Maxim: If you need this for each row, remove where, and it will run this on all rows of current for each row

Comment: @Maxim: Welcome as a new member of Stackoverflow. Please mark the answer as answered.

Comment: @Maxim: A small rule for you in the future. If you are going to set variables like in your post (with subquery)! ALWAYS use `TOP 1` as it will fail if you get more than one row

Answer (score 0):

You can directly update the query as below

```
UPDATE Prod SET priceDisc =((priceProd - priceProd) / 100 * disc)
```

This will update the data in all rows

Comment: And if I have not one, but more records?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit on your question?

Comment: The update will work for all rows. Its basically selecting the values from current row and calculating the discount and setting the current priceDisc column.